# Database for multilanguage design. double unique key referece to foreign key

Tags: sql, database-design, localization, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have to make my database able to translate some terms.
here is basic draw of my database:

first table(and many more like it):

```
create table objects
id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(50),
name_id int FOREIGN KEY,
```

Second table:

```
create table language
language varchar(20)
language_id PRIMARY KEY
```

Third table:

```
create table translations
language_id FOREIGN KEY,
name_id UNIQUE KEY,
translation varchar(50)
```

it looks like this:

OBJECTS:

```
id | name | name_id
___|______|________
1  |apple |1
```

LANGUAGE:

```
language_id | laguage
____________|________
1           | ENG
____________|________
2           | DEU
```

TRANSLATIONS:

```
language_id | name_id | translation
____________|_________|____________
1           | 1       | apple
____________|_________|____________
2           | 1       | apfel
```

Now, both columns in translations, language_id and name_id have to unique. but only one, name_id have to reference the foreign key in table objects.

is it possible to do? if not, whats the alternative?

Comment: The error message I get in Oracle: Make sure that the referencing columns match the referenced columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as you can create UNIQUE constraint in most databases:

```
-- Add unique constrain on two columns
ALTER TABLE TRANSLATIONS 
    ADD CONSTRAINT unq_translations UNIQUE (language_id, name_id);
-- Add foreign key constrain.
ALTER TABLE TRANSLATIONS 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_translations_name FOREIGN KEY (language_id, name_id) REFERENCES OBJECTS(language_id, id);
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not working. I get the message in Oracle that FK can not reference something that is not primary key or unique key.

Comment: it will help if you add what you tried to your question with error messages.

Answer (score 0):

**Use following alternative... Execute In order.**
 1. create table object(object_id number(10) primary key, object_name varchar(50));
 2. create table language(language_id number(10) primary key, language_name varchar(20));
 3. create table translation(translation_id number(10) primary key, translations varchar(50), object_id number(10), language_id number(10), foreign key(object_id) references object(object_id), foreign key(language_id) references language(language_id));

 4. alter table translation add unique(object_id, language_id);

Comment: I don't think that you get what I'm trying to do. First of all, PrimaryKey on table OBJECTS doesn't make sense. if you read my question properly, you would know that there is more tables than this one that have to be translated. and there is already a PrimaryKey in this table, I thought it was obvious.

Answer (score -1):

First, In the TRANSLATIONS table "name_id" is UNIQUE, i'm surprised how did you inserted duplicate entry in this column. Provide correct data for third table. 
In TRANSLATIONS table name_id shouldn't contain duplicate values.
Here only one column(with constraint) in TRANSLATIONS table that could contain duplicate entry is LANGUAGE_ID, and no benefit by making it unique as it is already unique in its parent table LANGUAGE.
However if you make column LANGUAGE_ID unique here, it will allow only those numbers of entries, that are in LANGUAGE table i.e. if LANGUAGE table contains **2** entries, you will be allowed to insert only **2** rows here in TRANSLATIONS table, AS I already said no benefit by doing this.

Comment: In TRANSTLATION table, column name_id have to contain duplicate value, because every object must be translated in both languages.

Comment: @PRO_gramista : so dont make it unique. you said in question that both columns have to be unique.

Comment: yes, this columns HAVE to be unique, or in another words: they must be unique.

Comment: You said this have to be unique and will contain duplicate entries ,how is it possible ?

Comment: they are both unique but only together. it means that every word is translated in english or german only once. together both language_id and name _id are unique

Comment: Okey use alternative...<br /> create table object(object_id number(10) primary key, object_name varchar(50));
create table language(language_id number(10) primary key, language_name varchar(20));
create table translation(translation_id number(10) primary key, translations varchar(50), object_id number(10), language_id number(10), foreign key(object_id) references object(object_id), foreign key(language_id) references language(language_id));
alter table translation add unique(object_id, language_id);